# Create multiple objects inside forloop

Tags: python, for-loop

Python noob here.

I want to create a bunch of list using a forloop.

They all need to in the form of l1, l2, l3, l4, etc.

I am trying to use the following code and I keep getting error, "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"

The following is the code and any help will be appreciated.

```
rets = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in range(0, len(rets)-1):
  object("L", str(i)) = [0]*(len(rets)-i)
```

So the objects need to be list that repeats 0. And the length should decrease by i. For eg, the last object will have length of 1.

I believe the error is related to the name of list but I am unable to fix it.

Comment: Dynamically creating variables is not good. Put them in a dict. If you really want to, look at `locals()` or `globals()` function.

Comment: Can you visualize desired output you wish to get ?

Comment: @AtaReenes Yes. They need to be list of zeros which I will use to store results from another for loop. All the list together will be like a matrix with lower triangle being 0s. Which is why the length of my list keeps reducing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is creating variable names (L1, L2, etc.), which can’t be done by creating an object like you did, and I’m not aware of any ways to dynamically creating variable names like this outside of PHP .

You can instead store all the variables insides a list, for example. Then you can pull those values out using a simple for loop.

```py
rets = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
values = []

for i in range(0, len(rets)-1):
  values.append([0]*(len(rets)-i))

for value in values:
  # Do something with value
```

You can use list comprehension for a cleaner syntax:

```py
rets = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
values = [[0]*(len(rets)-i) for i in range(1, len(rets)-1)]
```

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since i didn't get the question properly i will try to help as much as i can so if you want to achieve list of zeros with range you can use following code

```
rets = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list_of_lists = []

for item in rets:
    list_of_lists.append([0]*item)
```

it will give you the following output;

> [[0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

if you want to achieve something like ["L1,L2"] you can use the following snippet code;

```
for times in rets :
    added_list_here = []
    for i in range(times) :
        added_list_here.append(f'L{i}')
    
    list_of_lists.append(added_list_here)
```

and it will give you the following output;

> [['L0'], ['L0', 'L1'], ['L0', 'L1', 'L2'], ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3'],
> ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4'], ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5'],
> ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5', 'L6'], ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3',
> 'L4', 'L5', 'L6', 'L7'], ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5', 'L6',
> 'L7', 'L8'], ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5', 'L6', 'L7', 'L8',
> 'L9']]

Comment: I was not trying to do this. I just wanted to create ten variable named L0, L1.... L10 which have different lengths. But thank you so much for trying to help me.